# How can I access JasperReports's variables in Java code?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I want to access a VARIABLE from a *JasperReports* in my *Java* code.  More specifically, I need to know the REPORT_COUNT and the SUBREPORT_COUNT in my *Java* code after filling the report.  I've tried setting it as a property, but that doesn't work.

The report is scheduled, and I do not want to send the email if there is no data.  I've tried setting the "When No Data" to "print 0 pages," and then checking the page count in the java code.  This doesn't work if there is data in just the main or the just the subreport.  I want it to print 0 pages if either the main or the subreports have no data.

I'm sure this has been asked, but I can't find exactly what I need.  If someone could point me in the right direction, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject("path/to/your.jasper");

// prior to version 4.6.0, you should use JRFiller.createFiller(jasperReport)
JRFiller.createFiller(DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance(), jasperReport);

JasperPrint print = filler.fill(yourParameterMap, yourDatasource);

Object value = filler.getVariableValue(variableName); // here's what you need
```

Be advised that you won't be able to use `JasperFillManager.fillReport` anymore.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That is exactly what I needed.  I didn't know about the JRFiller.

Comment: The JRFiller.createFiller(jasperReport) is deprecated consider modifying your answer JRFiller.createFiller(DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance(),jasperReport);, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

@brunobastosg This won't work if we have reports that return one row with all null fields and 0 in data_found, in this case, you can't tell if it's really no data or not.